# Submitting parameters to Invoke-Expression

Tags: powershell

I've written a sample Powershell Script with name C:\Script\Scrip1.ps1
Below is the code

```
Function Testfunction(){

Param(
$Node1,
$Node2
)

$SQLNodes = @($Node1, $Node2)
foreach ($node in $SQLNodes)
{

#Some code below is dummy code
"$node" | Out-File C:\File1.txt -Append
}
}
```

When i try to call this function using invoke-Expression it doesn't work

Used below method with no luck

```
$string = 'C:\Script\Script1.ps1 Testfunction -Node1 "test" -Node2 "test2"'
Invoke-Expression $string
```

I have opened a PS Window and ran below command without luck

```
.\Script1.ps1 -Node1 Hello -Node2 Aquib
```

or

```
.\Script1.ps1 Testfunction -Node1 Hello -Node2 Aquib
```

I do not see any file1 under C:\File1

when when I open the script file and then run the function, it does work and generate the file.

Comment: Just don't use `Invoke-Expression`. It is [bad](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Comment: so I thought of creating a master powershell file from where I'll be running 3 PS1 file and giving them parameters from master. but seems like calling functions isn't working somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `Invoke-Expression` in your scenario.

If you want to make `Testfunction` visible in the current scope, you will need to "dot-source" your script:

```
PS C:\> . C:\Scripts\Script1.ps1
```

This executes `Script.ps1` in the current scope, which will define `Testfunction` in the current scope, and then you can run the function:

```
PS C:\> Testfunction -Node1 "Test1" -Node2 "Test2"
```

Another alternative is to skip defining `Testfunction` as a function in a script, and just use it as a script itself:

```
# Script file
param(
  $Node1,
  $Node2
)

$SQLNodes = @($Node1, $Node2)
foreach ($node in $SQLNodes) {
  #Some code below is dummy code
  "$node" | Out-File C:\File1.txt -Append
}
```

If you name the script `Testfunction.ps1`, you can run it by typing the script's name:

```
PS C:\> C:\Scripts\Testfunction.ps1 -Node1 "Test1" -Node2 "Test2"
```

Comment: that's a good alternative Bill. I was creating a master PS1 from where I'll be running the 3 Different PS1 hence i was calling the PS file. thanks :)